# how do I edit a Google Now reminder from my desktop?

Tags: google-now

I can see them, I can delete them but I can't figure out how to edit them. For instance, I have a reminder for "Payday" every two weeks -- but the start date was apparently wrong. I can edit it on my phone but I see no way to edit them in Chrome, even if I'm signed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view & edit your Google reminders on https://calendar.google.com.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about _Google Now_ reminders.

Comment: I believe they do get added to Google Calendar. Check it out...

Comment: I can confirm this is true. I just created a reminder with Google Now and it appears on Google Calendar in my "Reminders" calendar. When I edited it on Google Calendar, the changes appear in Google Now. (That includes changing the date.)

Comment: This assumes, of course, you've made the switch on Google Calendar from "Tasks" to "Reminders".

Answer (score 0):

In Google Inbox app: 
https://inbox.google.com/reminders?pli=1

You can click on the reminders tab on the left hand side.

[image: Left Hand Side of Google Inbox]